# Finding the Nth smallest number in an unsorted array using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I've scoured the forums and can't find an example of how to find the Nth smallest number in an array in combination with scannner, so I'm sorry if this has been answered here before. Also, is there any way to display the number of comparisons that was made by the program to find an element within the array? I've attached an image of the assignment instructions if it will help. [assignment instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7PDw.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("IDS201 HW3:\n");
        System.out.println("1. Generate " + RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT + " random integer unsorted list.\n");
        int[] randomNumbers = generateRandomNUmbers();
        System.out.print("\n2. Search value? ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = stdin.nextInt();
        int count = search(randomNumbers, x);
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + " is not in the list");
        }
        
        System.out.println("\n3. Sort the list:");
        sort(randomNumbers);
        System.out.print("Now the Array after Sorting is :\n\n");
        display(randomNumbers);
    } 
 
private static final int  RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT = 50;

private static void display(int[] randomNumbers) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT; i++) {
        System.out.print(randomNumbers[i] + ",");
        count++;
        if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println();
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}

private static int[] generateRandomNUmbers() {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT];
    for (int index = 0; index < RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT; index++) {
        randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
    display(randomNumbers);
    return randomNumbers;
}

private static int search(int[] randomNumbers, int x) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (randomNumbers[i] == x) {
            System.out.println("\nFound " + x + " in array [" + i + "]");
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static int[] sort(int[] randomNumbers) {
    int size = randomNumbers.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (randomNumbers[i] > randomNumbers[j]) {
                int temp = randomNumbers[i];
                randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[j];
                randomNumbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

}

Comment: Your question says you look for the n-th smallest number in the array but your code searches how many instances of an element you read from the Scanner are there in your List. Also, how is using a scanner any different from searching n-th smallest number in an array?

Comment: @CanBayar Thank you for your comment. I have to find number of instances of an element as well as finding the n-th smallest number in the array. I would think using scanner to find the n-th smallest element is different from a program where the n-th smallest element is just inserted directly into the code

Answer (score 0):

You can find the order statistics algorithm to find the k-th smallest element in O(n) time [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/?ref=rp). For the Scanner part, you don't need anything other than reading k from the command line and passing it into the algorithm. Nothing really different from the original algorithm, both takes a parameter k and in this case, you read the parameter k from the command line.

**Note:** There are other approaches to the k-th smallest element problem, but they are slower. For example, you can sort your array and then find the k-th element from the last index. You can also find other approaches from previous entries on the given link.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    System.out.println ("IDS201 HW3:\n");
    System.out.println ("1. Generate " + RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT +
            " random integer unsorted list.\n");
    int[] randomNumbers = generateRandomNUmbers ();
      System.out.print ("\n2. Search value? ");
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);
    int x = stdin.nextInt ();
    int count = search (randomNumbers, x);
    if (count == 0)
      {
    System.out.println (x + " is not in the list");
      }
    else
      {
    System.out.println ("compared " + count + " times to search");
      }
    System.out.print ("\n2. Nth Smallest value? ");
    int nth_value = stdin.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("K'th smallest element is " +
              nth_search (randomNumbers, 0, RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT-1,nth_value));
    System.out.println ("\n3. Sort the list:");
    sort (randomNumbers);
    System.out.print ("Now the Array after Sorting is :\n\n");
    display (randomNumbers);
  }

  private static final int RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT = 50;

  private static int partition (int[]randomNumbers, int l, int r)
  {
    int x = randomNumbers[r], i = l;
    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++)
      {
    if (randomNumbers[j] <= x)
      {
        int temp = randomNumbers[i];
        randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[j];
        randomNumbers[j] = temp;
        i++;
      }
      }
    int temp = randomNumbers[i];
    randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[r];
    randomNumbers[r] = temp;
    return i;
  }


  private static void display (int[]randomNumbers)
  {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT; i++)
      {
    System.out.print (randomNumbers[i] + ",");
    count++;
    if (count == 10)
      {
        System.out.println ();
        count = 0;
      }
      }
  }

  private static int[] generateRandomNUmbers ()
  {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT];
    for (int index = 0; index < RANDOM_NUMBER_COUNT; index++)
      {
    randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random () * 100);
      }
    display (randomNumbers);
    return randomNumbers;
  }

  private static int search (int[]randomNumbers, int x)
  {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++)
      {
    if (randomNumbers[i] == x)
      {
        System.out.println ("\nFound " + x + " in array [" + i + "]");
        count++;
      }
      }
    return count;
  }

  private static int nth_search (int[]randomNumbers, int l, int r, int k)
  {
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l +1)
      {
    int pos = partition (randomNumbers, l, r);
    if (pos - l == k - 1)
      return randomNumbers[pos];
    if (pos - l > k - 1)
      return nth_search (randomNumbers, l, pos - 1, k);
    return nth_search (randomNumbers, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1);
      }
    return -1;
  }

  private static int[] sort (int[]randomNumbers)
  {
    int size = randomNumbers.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
      {
        if (randomNumbers[i] > randomNumbers[j])
          {
        int temp = randomNumbers[i];
        randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[j];
        randomNumbers[j] = temp;
          }
      }
      }
    return randomNumbers;
  }
}
```

**nth smallest term function**

```
private static int nth_search (int[]randomNumbers, int l, int r, int k)
  {
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l +1)
      {
    int pos = partition (randomNumbers, l, r);
    if (pos - l == k - 1)
      return randomNumbers[pos];
    if (pos - l > k - 1)
      return nth_search (randomNumbers, l, pos - 1, k);
    return nth_search (randomNumbers, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1);
      }
    return -1;
  }
```

**and 2nd function**

```
private static int partition (int[]randomNumbers, int l, int r)
  {
    int x = randomNumbers[r], i = l;
    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++)
      {
    if (randomNumbers[j] <= x)
      {
        int temp = randomNumbers[i];
        randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[j];
        randomNumbers[j] = temp;
        i++;
      }
      }
    int temp = randomNumbers[i];
    randomNumbers[i] = randomNumbers[r];
    randomNumbers[r] = temp;
    return i;
  }
```